# Too few arguments to call

Tags: c, pointers

My teacher isn't willing to help me with my error so I don't know where else to go. On line 19, `addition();`, the error says that there are too few arguments in the function call and I'm not sure why this is. I am a beginner programmer, but I have called functions before so I'm not sure why I am getting a problem now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addition(int *change);

int main(void)
{
    int num = 10;
    printf("Name \t Address \t Value\n");
    printf("%s \t %p \t %d\n", "num", &num, num);

    int *change = &num;
    printf("Change:  %p\n", change);

    *change = 100;
    printf("The value of num is %d \n", num);
    printf("The value of change is %d \n", *change);

    addition();

    return 0;
}

int addition(int *change)
{
    int input;
    int result = input + *change;

    printf("Input a value ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("The result will be change (%d) + input (%d)\n", *change, input);
    printf("Result: %d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `addition` function is declared to take one argument. Count the number of arguments between the parentheses in the line `addition();`. You're missing one.

Comment: So what do you think this error means?

Comment: `addition();` takes an `int*` argument. But you are not passing anything. Do you mean  to pass `addition(change);`?

Comment: I think I have an error because nothing is being passed to the function

Comment: @Jasonvilla yes you have to pas an _int*_

Comment: ty, I just don't understand though why I got alot of down votes for asking this...

Comment: I imagine the downvotes are because the answer to the question is in the error message in the question.

Comment: but my problem was I didn't know how to fix it

Comment: @Jasonvilla The fix is to pass the arguments to `addition` that you want to pass to `addition`. If you do not understand this, then you have not learned the material.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this would be better suited to a comment, but I lack the required reputation to post comments...

When you're calling a function, you often have to supply some information.  If I walked up to you and commanded "Add!" you might reply "what should I add?"  This is essentially what your error message is telling you.  You're issuing a command, but you're not giving it enough information to complete that command.

You can find what additional information is required by a function by glancing at its declaration.  In this case, your function declaration is:

```
addition(int *change)
```

meaning that, in order to function properly, the function requires a pointer to an integer (int *).  Every time you call the addition function, you have to supply this argument so that the function knows the number to which it is expected to add.